# OpenLayers 4 and MapServer 7.0.4 HTML template

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver, html, getfeatureinfo

I would like to know if it is possible to render directly a HTML template retrieved from a MapServer WMS GetFeatureInfo call.

The documentation explains that the API uses ol.Format.GML2 to read features [Here the API DOC](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.WMSGetFeatureInfo.html). No mention about HTML.

Here the template I would like to render: [HTML template by MapServer](http://geoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/cgi-wms/mffpecofor.fcgi?&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=sh_zone_veg&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=-7974704,6285285,-7974482,6285410&WIDTH=1720&HEIGHT=886&QUERY_LAYERS=sh_zone_veg&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&X=762&Y=685)

I would like to not know if there is a "direct" way, not as shown in this 
[example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say _not as shown in this example_.  In the example it has `{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'}` which is the HTML response.  Did you try it?

Comment: I agree, it's not clear.

Comment: In this example, https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-layers.html?q=getfeatureinfo , the response management is seamless. Into the other example (original post), you have to call another parametrer to cast correctly you response. More clear?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add further details

Comment: In the second example you post there is no GetFeatureInfo request, instead an XML file is parsed which pretends to be the response of a GetFeatureInfo request, where the info_format was GML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this purely from the WMS interface standards perspective, we can see that there is no default format for a GetFeatureInfo request (so if OpenLayers suggests it is GML, then that is a mistake).

Looking at WMS 1.1.1 we can see that the info_format parameter is optional (so any software compliant to this specification can define its own default).  As far as I can tell both GeoServer and MapServer default to plain text as the default when making a WMS 1.1.1 GetFeatureInfo request and not specifying the info_format parameter, or specifying the parameter as empty like `info_format&`

For the WMS 1.3.0 specification there is still no default format specified, but this time there is a requirement to supply an info_format parameter as part of your GetFeatureInfo request.

It might be that OpenLayers defaults to using GML as the info_format for a GetFeatureInfo request, and if so it can only guarantee such a format by requesting it using the info_format parameter.

To ensure an HTML response you would be wise to always specify that format using the `INFO_FORMAT=text/html&` as part of your GetFeatureInfo request.